# Why is this array not big enough?

Tags: c, memory

I have been running this random walk simulation for a while now and I keep getting an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from Xcode. Its printing out a large part of the simulation though.

I think its running out of memory for some reason but I am not sure why.

If I go towards the end of the array I edited it so I don't get within 100 spaces of the edge (by editing the variable steps to steps -100). This works but I would like to know whats going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
double** places;  
places = (double**) malloc(steps*sizeof(double*));  
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)places[i] = (double*) malloc(2*sizeof(double));  

for (i = 0; i< steps/*, exit*/; i++) {
    // Find the angle of movement 
    angle = getRand()*360; 
    // Take a step
    xPos+= STEP*cos(angle);
    yPos+= STEP*sin(angle);
    //Write Step to array
    places[i][1] = xPos;
    places[i][2] = yPos;
    //Write Step to File
    fprintf(ff, "%d %lf %lf\n",i,xPos,yPos);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array indexes start at zero.

Did you mean to write this?

```
    places[i][0] = xPos; //Zeroth element is considered the first element
    places[i][1] = yPos; //Second element
```

Comment: Oh thank God! Now I feel like an idiot. I knew this but i totally mixed it up.

Comment: No problems. It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated an array of the proper size (steps x 2), but you're writing to the wrong offsets on the sub-arrays. They should be [0] and [1], not [1] and [2].

`[2]` is actually the **3rd** array element, so you're writing outside of the subarray's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The inner arrays (located at `places[i]`) have space for two elements - indexed by `[0]` and `[1]`, since array indices generally start at zero in C. Here, you index them with `[1]` and `[2]`. You need to use `[0]` and `[1]` instead, or allocate enough space for three elements (and waste the space allocated for `[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts from 0.

This should be:

```
places[i][0] = xPos;
places[i][1] = yPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off by one. Arrays in C are zero-based, so the first element is at position 0. You need to change your assignment to the places array as follows:

```
// Write Step to array
places[i][0] = xPos;
places[i][1] = yPos;
```